# Video conference/chat tool that can be embedded in own website needed

Tags: browsers, video, chat

We are looking for a means (a tool, a commercial service) to **enable a closed user group to start a live video conference in a browser**, as part of the company website. Something like Skype, but embedded and available for everybody that has access to the page into which the tool is embedded.

Most services require registration and the creation of a chat room on their website, or, as Skype or similar solutions, the installation of an extra software. What we need is a **solution with some kind of a "hidden login", performed by the site's client script** (which knows who the user is and forwards the credentials to the service).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Openmeetings](http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/) perfectly embeds into web sites

Comment: Very cool tool. I have not yet tried this, but from the docs and website it seems to be covering all requirements.

Comment: did you try it with your website? @olaf..

Comment: @Java D: Never in a real scenario, just testing. Seems fine, but the customer went another way...

Answer (score 2):

[Kanyo](http://www.kanyo.co.uk/) or [eye network](http://www.eyenetwork.com/) should be able to help you out, you'd need to talk to their tech people about implementation though.

Comment: Thanks, will do. So far on their websites I don't see browser solutions, but I'll check further.

Comment: @Olaf I setup a system a couple of years back using Kanyo's tech - it's not a product they sell explicitly, but one they can make available to you for a price.